# Add Domain access to Square API

Tags: square-connect

I need my customers to pay for their accounts on their own website. Using only the API how do I add access to any domain of my choice to pay using my payment form? I already have everything setup where their user and card are setup on Square's accounts though I'm having issues with the form working on their website domain names.

When submitting the form the part that requests the nonce encounters the following:

> Invalid postMessage origin: "https://www.example.com"

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You want your customers to add your payment form to their website so that they can pay you by checking out on their own site?

Comment: @tristansokol They should be able to pay their bill for using my web platform at their own website instead of having to go to my website and setup a second account. I have total control over all server-side technology so there is no security conflict if that is a concern; I host everything.

Comment: You offer web hosting services? And you want end users to pay for hosting from their own domain name? Is there an example of a site that does this that I could look at? I don't think I'm getting it. Regardless, you can host the payment form from any url, as long as it https. If your clients wanted to put your payment form into their page, they could.

Comment: @tristansokol I'm encountering some sort of error where the domain isn't being accepted when obtaining the nonce. My main domain is jabcreations.com, I'm testing from fixedfirefox.com to emulate a client paying from their domain name.

Comment: I see that you added your error. Does card nonce generation still work?

Comment: @tristansokol I've posted a bug report here: https://github.com/square/connect-api-specification/issues/93